# how to run android apk file on blackberry os 10 simulator from eclipse

Tags: blackberry, simulator

i want to run apk file on blackberry simulator from eclipse.  What are steps to get the blackberry simulator and how to convert apk to blackberry understandable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Follow these steps:

1. install eclipse 4.2.2
2. install android sdk (maximum api level is 18)
3. install adt version from https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.3.zip
4. download the blackberry plug in from
   http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/
5. install bb os 10 simulator from http://developer.blackberry.com/android/downloads/fetch/BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_3_0-698-Mac-201406131353.dmg
6. install vmplayer.
7. Run vm player and bb simulator.
8. After that create
   a new application in eclipse and right click on application.

9.it shows the blackberry option select export app it opens window
    asking the ip address of simulator. The ip address is available at
    bottom of the simulator.